# Mobx: Observable array does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, mobx

I am trying to understand how to use observable array with Mobx.

I have a hard time to figure out why this:

```
let entities = observable([]);
entities[0] = "foo";
autorun(() =>{
  console.log(entities);
});
```

writes:

```
[$mobx: Object]
0: (...)
1: (...)
2: (...)
3: (...)
4: (...)
5: (...)
6: (...)
7: (...)
8: (...)
9: (...)
10: (...)
11: (...)
12: (...)
13: (...)
14: (...)
15: (...)
16: (...)
17: (...)
...
999: (...)
```

Instead of a classic array?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Figure out!

As stated in the docs

> Bear in mind that Array.isArray(observable([])) will yield false, so whenever you need to pass an observable array to an external library, it is a good idea to create a shallow copy before passing it to other libraries or built-in functions (which is good practice anyway) by using array.slice() or array.peek(). So Array.isArray(observable([]).slice()) will yield true.

The doc exemple show us a `todos.filter()` which could lead to confusion because `todos` looks like a real JS Array. But it is not.

So for my exemple to work I just have to `console.log(entities.slice())` which will display a real JS array.

Comment: I had this problem using `<select multiple={true} value={this.props.val}>`, ie not an external lib, just a standard html field. Console was giving me a warning and initial selection wasn't showing up. Changing to `this.props.val.sice()` fixed it.

Comment: kind of an ugly hack, wish there was a better solution for this, somehow to define observable arrays as pure arrays

Comment: Same Problem...i get the following error : Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Comment: also fixed for me *"mobx read out of bounds [0]"* warning when passing the observable array _gifted chat_ module.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to log mobx observable is with `toJS` method

```
import { toJS } from 'mobx';

class Store {
  @observable
  fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana'];

  constructor() {
    console.log('this.views :', toJS(this.data));
  }
}

export default new Store();
```

Hope this help. [Source](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#tojs)

Comment: I think this is deprecated now. That's why we need to use slice()

Comment: The link "Source" is giving 404 - Not Found

Comment: I guess the documentation changed, source url updated